# Vim auto indentation

Tags: indentation, filetype-javascript

I am using Vim with Pathogen, vim-jsx, and vim-javascript.

I have trouble getting the correct indentation. When I am breaking one line that is too long into several pieces (without adding new blocks), the next line loses its correct indentation (and the next one after that, etc). This is really annoying and blocks me from using `gg=G`.

Let me illustrate:

[image]

In the gif, I am breaking the `conversationPage` line, and then reindenting the next two lines with `==`.

I have no such problems with my other `vim-js-indent` plugin, thoguh, but it doesn't support JSX. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I've figured out a way to do this in my environment. I had to shrink and cut pangloss vim-javascript a little bit. Here's my fork:

https://github.com/seavan/vim-javascript-plus

You should install it along with vim-jsx in your bundle directory. It will work.

I removed some of the latest pangloss updates to make it work. Hopefully I will merge them back after a while.
[image]